# Low performance on validation set after training MobileNetV3Small model for custom image classification task

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, mobilenet

I'm new to the Tensorflow Keras API, and thought I would use it with the [tensorflow-metal plugin from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) to train a custom MobileNetV3Small model on my M1 Pro MacBook for the task of image classification. This is for my app [DeTeXt](https://venkatasg.net/apps/detext), that classifies drawings into LaTeX symbols. Currently I'm using a MobileNetV2 model that I had trained on a GPU cluster using the PyTorch API ([code here](https://github.com/venkatasg/DeTeXt-Supplementary/blob/main/train-detex.py)).

Here is the code I use to train my custom network from scratch on the images I have (there are 1098 image classes):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pdb

EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 128
LEARNING_RATE = 0.003
SEED=1220

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    # Load train and validation data
    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
                                '/Volumes/detext/drawings/',
                                color_mode="grayscale",
                                seed=SEED,
                                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                labels='inferred',
                                label_mode='int',
                                image_size=(200,300),
                                validation_split=0.1,
                                subset='training')
    
    val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
                                '/Volumes/detext/drawings/',
                                color_mode="grayscale",
                                seed=SEED,
                                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                labels='inferred',
                                label_mode='int',
                                image_size=(200,300),
                                validation_split=0.1,
                                subset='validation')
    
    # Get the class names
    class_names = train_ds.class_names
    num_classes = len(class_names)

    # Create model
    model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV3Small(
        input_shape=(200,300,1), alpha=1.0, minimalistic=False, 
        include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, classes=num_classes,
        pooling=None, dropout_rate=0.2, classifier_activation="softmax",
        include_preprocessing=True)

    # Compile model
    model.compile(
           optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE),
           loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
           metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

    # Training
    model.fit(train_ds, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=val_ds)

    model.save('./saved_model3/')
```

While the training runs smooth and fast with the metal plugin, the validation accuracy is very low after 5 epochs, and I suspect it is either predicting the same class every time, or there is an error somewhere in my setup above. I have tried rescaling the inputs myself (and removing rescaling layer from model), but no matter what I try, the validation accuracy it outputs is really low. Here is the output (warnings and all) after 3 epochs:

```
Found 210454 files belonging to 1098 classes.
Using 189409 files for training.
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Pro

systemMemory: 32.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 10.67 GB

2021-12-16 13:52:59.275089: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2021-12-16 13:52:59.275417: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
Found 210454 files belonging to 1098 classes.
Using 21045 files for validation.
Epoch 1/5
2021-12-16 13:53:03.916564: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-12-16 13:53:03.925966: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2021-12-16 13:53:03.926644: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1480/1480 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.7888 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.56492021-12-16 14:03:11.365840: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1480/1480 [==============================] - 626s 422ms/step - loss: 1.7888 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5649 - val_loss: 10.6702 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0031
Epoch 2/5
1480/1480 [==============================] - 624s 422ms/step - loss: 1.1022 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.6713 - val_loss: 8.3791 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0195
Epoch 3/5
1480/1480 [==============================] - 626s 423ms/step - loss: 0.9983 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.6904 - val_loss: 9.1081 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0181
```

### Update

The issue seems to be specific to certain types of operations/layers in Tensorflow not playing well with Metal, and specifically with respect to the validation accuracy (similar to [this issue](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696474)). When I build my own custom model with convolutions like so:

```
    model = Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 1, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 1, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 1, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes),
  layers.Softmax()
])
```

training proceeds as expected, with a high validation accuracy as well. Below is the output for the above model:

```
Found 210454 files belonging to 1098 classes.
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Pro

systemMemory: 32.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 10.67 GB

2021-12-21 12:27:24.005759: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2021-12-21 12:27:24.006206: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
Found 210454 files belonging to 1098 classes.
Using 31568 files for validation.
2021-12-21 12:27:26.965648: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-12-21 12:27:26.968717: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2021-12-21 12:27:26.969214: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1645/1645 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.1246 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.52732021-12-21 12:32:57.475358: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1645/1645 [==============================] - 353s 214ms/step - loss: 2.1246 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.5273 - val_loss: 1.3041 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.6558
2021-12-21 12:33:19.600146: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
```

However, the very same code with the MobileNetV3Small model (instead of my custom model) produces the following output:

```
Found 210454 files belonging to 1098 classes.
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Pro

systemMemory: 32.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 10.67 GB

2021-12-21 12:34:46.754598: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2021-12-21 12:34:46.754793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
Found 210454 files belonging to 1098 classes.
Using 31568 files for validation.
2021-12-21 12:34:49.742015: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-12-21 12:34:49.747397: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2021-12-21 12:34:49.747606: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1645/1645 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.4072 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.46722021-12-21 12:41:28.137948: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
1645/1645 [==============================] - 415s 252ms/step - loss: 2.4072 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4672 - val_loss: 21.6091 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0131
2021-12-21 12:41:46.017580: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
/Users/venkat/miniforge3/envs/tf-metal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:494: CustomMaskWarning: Custom mask layers require a config and must override get_config. When loading, the custom mask layer must be passed to the custom_objects argument.
  warnings.warn('Custom mask layers require a config and must override '
```

The validation loss/accuracy is hilariously bad, and I find that the model constantly predicts the same class. My guess is that MobileNetV3Small seems to contain some operations/layers that don't work well with `tensorflow-metal` for whatever reason, and only Apple Engineers can fix this problem at a low level.

Comment: It looks like both losses are going lower and the validation accuracy is increased between the epochs. What do the metrics look like after 5 epochs? It could be that the model just need some more training.

Comment: I've edited the output to include results from one more epoch, and the validation accuracy barely goes up. I'm concerned that the validation accuracy is so much lower than training accuracy though - that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Could you what the results are if you create just the training set from your whole data, and the use
`model.fit(train_ds, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split=0.1)`? This way, the validation split is done automatically when fitting.

Comment: I can't do exactly that, since `fit` will take the argument `validation_split` only if the input is a numpy array, rather than a dataset in my case. However I have tried setting the train dataset to be the entire data, and then subsetting validation from that, and the results are similar.

Comment: @sakumoil see my update above - Tensorflow-metal seems to have issues with certain models